# Create issue on bitbucket api

Tags: php, bitbucket, guzzle

I'm trying to create an issue on bitbucket with title and content, but it fails with the error:

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"fields": {"content": "expected a dictionary"}, "message": "Bad request"}}
```

However, if I don't send the `content`, and only the `title`, it works and the issue is created

Here is the relevant code

```
$response = $this->getClient()->post(static::URL . "/repositories/{$repository}/issues", [
        "body" => [
            "title"     => "a title",
            "content"   => "the issue body
        ]
    ]);
```

I've checked the docs but they are not really acurate

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/issues

Any idea?

**Edit:**
I found out that using the api v1.0 it works, but only the api 2.0 gives that error message

so
`POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my-user/my-repo/issues`
  fails but

`POST https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/my-user/my-repo/issues`

works

Comment: What are you trying to send as  content in your issue? its working fine for me

Comment: @VuralAcar A simple string fails "content" => "the issue body"

Comment: I found that with api 1.0 works, but is the 2.0 that doesn't

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol Did you ever solve this using v2? I'm stuck at this same issue. Description doesn't work and content gives me the same error as above.

Comment: No.. just used v1

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol I solved it, but for Android. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @GregMcMullen  I solved it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error message while creating an issue using Bitbucket API v2 but in *android*. After tinkering for a while, I found that it works if you specify `content` as an object with `raw` attribute.

In PHP, It would be,

```
$response = $this->getClient()->post(static::URL . "/repositories/{$repository}/issues", [
        "body" => [
            "title"     => "a title",
            "content"   => [
                "raw" => "the issue body"
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

In Postman,

```
{
    "title":"title of the issue",
    "content":{
        "raw":"this should be the description"
    }
}
```

body as `raw` with `Content-Type : application/json` in header.

If you're using Android(for which this I was looking for), you need to post as `json` using `JsonObjectRequest`

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put("title", "title of the issue");

JSONObject content = new JSONObject();
content.put("raw", "this should be the description");

body.put("content", content);

JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(<url>, body, <Response listener>, <Error Listener>);
```